# How spammers publish spam tweets very fast

Tags: twitter

I am a little bit confused how spammers publish spam tweets in twitter.

For example when I see the spam tweet I wont retweet it since I read the content before retweeting and so the spam tweets should not distribute so fast but I have heard some of them becomes famous very soon!!

is it because other people retweet spams before reading it? Please help me to understand the process . I appreciate any help

Comment: This question may be better suited for the Web Application Stack Exchange Site http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter

Answer (score 1):

Spam tweeting is often done with an automated out of the box program such as 
Automated Tweet: http://www.automatedtweet.com/
Hoot Suite: https://hootsuite.com/
and a variety of other tools available in the marketplace.
It should be noted that Twitter does not condone spam tweeting and the above information is for reference purposes only. Twitter is constantly working to weed out spammers and overuse of tools like these can get accounts banned.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am wondering when someone use these automated tools how come the resulted tweet becomes very popular. Is it because many people retweet it (because most of them are advertisement and people wont retweet them).I do not understand why some of them expands very fast.)